# Charset in browsercomponent

Tags: android, codenameone

I've got a problem when using the BrowserComponent in Codenameone: When calling the dropbox authorization URL in the BrowserComponent within the simulator, the page is displayed, but the charset seems wrong:

[image: android charset problem]

I cannot read the text displayed in the browser (nonsense text) - but when I copy & paste the text from the browser component to the texteditor, the text is readable. What can I do to make the text readable in the browser component?

Here's the code I use to use the browser component:

```
Form tmpBrowserForm = new Form(„DropBoxAccess“);
tmpBrowserForm.setLayout(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
WebBrowser tmpBrowser = new WebBrowser(„https://www.dropbox.com/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=xyz“);
tmpBrowserForm.add(tmpBrowser);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the encoding for the page in the browser is set correctly, if you load the text to a String and set it using the page methods make sure that you loaded the String with the correct native encoding.

E.g. never use new `String(byte[])`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I did not find a way to set the encoding in the Browser-Component of Codenameone - and the page is shown correct in a native browser on my laptop. What setting in the Browser-Component can be used to change the encoding?

Comment: I'm guessing here since you didn't include any code and there are **many** ways to show the component. There is a meta tag for encoding in the page, is it set?

Comment: There is a meta set in the head of the page:  

    <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

I use a very simple code to include the browser component:

    Form tmpBrowserForm = new Form(„DropBoxAccess“);
    tmpBrowserForm.setLayout(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

    WebBrowser tmpBrowser = new WebBrowser(„https://www.dropbox.com/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=abc“);
    tmpBrowserForm.add(tmpBrowser);

Comment: The code is unreadable in the comment, please edit your question and post the code there and comment here so I get notified that the post was changed. You shouldn't put a browser component in a `BoxLayout` as this will cause layout problems on the device place it in the center of a border layout on the form. Notice that this might be a problem in the JavaFX browser so I suggest testing it on devices to see if it works there

Comment: I added the code in the description now. And of cause I will change the layout to BorderLayout.

Comment: The code seems incorrect and the URL is wrong but did you try it on a device too? It's very possible that this is a simulator only issue.

Comment: Sorry - I made a mistake when posting the dropbox-URL. The URL in my app is correct - it was just a mistake when I posted the code. The error also occurs when executing the app on a real android device. But it's interesting, that the page is shown correct when using the native browser with Display.getInstance().execute(<the url>);

Comment: Can you post a device screenshot? Can you also change the code to use `BrowserComponent` and not `WebBrowser`?

Comment: I solved the problem by switching to the native-browser with using Display.getInstance().execute(<URL>).  This solution is much more better in handling and displaying.

Comment: I have a similar problem, I am trying to display chinese, I dont want to launch external browser, I have used meta tag to set utf8, displays fine on android but on ios it displays as garbage. I have just noticed I do  out.write(html.getBytes()); would that be an issue? but also i cant think of another way to write to an output stream ?

Comment: I tried Util.writeUTF(html, new DataOutputStream(out));  - same problem on ios using BrowserComponent (displays garbage), weird thing is if I add a new Label or button to a form with the html in it displays the chinese fine, it just wont display properly in the BrowserComponent on ios.

Comment: Write UTF encodes as UTF but it looks like you are trying to write a binary file which is a different thng